# What can i do to update the android version of my android device if there is no available update available for my device?

Tags: updates

my device is ondo vi10. it is a android tablet i bought from a IT Fair. The current android version is 4.0.3. What are some ways i can update it?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no official update available, your only option is to flash a custom ROM on your device. This operation is potentially dangerous if you don't know what you are doing and you may brick your device. The tricky part is not the installation (which is selecting the ROM into a software and uploading via USB, or even simpler, booting in recovery with the new software on SD Card - dead simple, a button combination). The tricky part is to find a correct new ROM/software/image for your device. ROMs are not available for less known devices such as "Ondo" vi10 (did you want to say Onda?). But there are ROMs available for some other --identical-- devices. With the same camera, cpu, chipset, ram amount, etc. And that will work on your tablet. Do some research, see what other people used with that tablet. I'm sure someone "flashed" some custom firmware on that Ondo/Onda before.

Comment: Hahah! Yupp i want to say Onda (Sorry typo) thanks alot. hmm i cant really find any other similar devices with flashed custom firmware.